# jqueryui autocomplete with json does nothing

Tags: asp.net, json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

BLUF: I have jqueryui autocomplete wired into an AJAX-y JSON-y DB lookup.  It calls the page correct, and the page returns JSON.  However, it doesn't actually load those results into the UI.  It appears to very slowly do nothing.

Relevant JS:

```
$(function () {
            $("#searchtext").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.getJSON("<%=ResolveUrl("~/getPeople?prefix=") %>" + request.term, function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.dealers, function (value, key) {
                            return {
                                label: value,
                                value: key
                            };
                        }));
                    });
                },
                select: function (e, i) {
                    $("#personID").val(i.item.val);
                },
                minLength: 2,
                delay: 100
            });
        });
```

Code of getPeople.aspx:

```
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "text/json")
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/json")
    Dim prefix
    prefix = Request.QueryString("prefix")
    
    Dim PDU_CS = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("PDU").ConnectionString
    Using PDU_Connection As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection()
        PDU_Connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("PDU").ConnectionString
        Using PDU_Command As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand()
            PDU_Command.CommandText = "select id, [name] FROM vw_Staff WHERE [name] LIKE @searchtext + '%'"
            PDU_Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchtext", prefix)
            PDU_Command.Connection = PDU_Connection
            PDU_Connection.Open()
            Using sdr As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = PDU_Command.ExecuteReader()
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                dt.Load(sdr)
                Dim sData As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt)
                Response.Write(sData)
            End Using
            PDU_Connection.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
```

Actual output from getPeople.aspx?prefix=Gibson

```
[{"id":5854,"name":"GIBSON,  NICHOLAS"}]
```

Comment: Would you want to use `value.name` and `value.id` in your Map?

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest two changes:

```
$(function() {
  $("#searchtext").autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
        $.getJSON("<%=ResolveUrl("~/getPeople?prefix=") %>" + request.term, function (data) {
          response($.map(data.dealers, function(value, key) {
            return {
              label: value.name,
              value: value.id
            };
          }));
        });
    },
    select: function(e, i) {
      $("#personID").val(i.item.value);
      return false;
    },
    minLength: 2,
    delay: 100
  });
});
```

1. Since you're passing an Array of Object to `$.map()`, you need interact with each Object, in this case the `value` of the array.
2. `select` has `ui`, in your case, just `i`, and it is `i.item.value`, not `i.item.val`.

Reference: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

Comment: I made the changes you suggested (manually, and then copy/paste), and see no difference in behavior.  No errors are thrown, no autocomplete is shown.

Comment: @sapph what Libraries are you loading? What appears in Console?

Comment: jquery-3.3.1.js, modernizr-2.8.3.js, jquery-ui-1.12.1.js, bootstrap-3.3.7.js, jquery.validate.1.19.2.js

Nothing shows in console.

Comment: @sapph what do you see in the Network console? If nothing is showing up, this suggests that `response` is getting an empty array.

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant the script console. Network shows the call to getPeople.aspx?prefix=Gibson with a 200 response and the body as shown in the question.

Comment: @sapph something is not adding up, my code should work. Can you provide your resulting HTML in your post please?